# Add a switch statement in JS based on a HTML <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I am learning how to integrate JavaScript into HTML documents and want to build a simple calculator app.

The idea is that there will be two  elements from which the app takes the arguments and a  element to choose calculation type. I have managed to get the numbers working flawlessly, however I can't manage to get the select's value in any way.

Relevant HTML:

```
            <div class="calc">
                <h1 id = "title">Your Calculation Results:</h1>
                <div id = "results"></div>
                <input type="number" id="firstNum">
                <select id="calcType" name="calcType">
                    <option value="add">+</option>
                    <option value="subtract">-</option>
                    <option value="multiply">*</option>
                    <option value="divide">/</option>
                    <option value="modulo">%</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" id="secondNum">
                <button type="button" onclick="clickHandler()">Let's Calc!</button>
            </div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function clickHandler() {
    let num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
    let num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
    let calcTypes = document.getElementById("calcType"); 
    let selectedType = calcTypes.options[calcTypes.selectedIndex].value;

    let add = `Addition: ${num1} + ${num2} = ${parseFloat(num1)+parseFloat(num2)}`;
    let subtract = `Subtraction: ${num1} - ${num2} = ${num1-num2}`
    let multiply = `Multiplication: ${num1} * ${num2} = ${num1*num2}`
    let divide = `Division: ${num1} / ${num2} = ${(num1/num2).toFixed(3)}`
    let remainder = `Remainder: ${num1} % ${num2} = ${num1%num2}`

    switch(selectedType) {
        case "add": document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = `<p>${add}</p>`;
        case "subtract": document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = `<p>${subtract}</p>`;
        case "multiply": document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = `<p>${multiply}</p>`;
        case "divide": document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = `<p>${divide}</p>`;
        case "modulo": document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = `<p>${remainder}</p>`;
        default: document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = `<p>${add}</p>`;
    }
}
```

What ends up happening is that no matter what option I select, the app always renders the `default` case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: When you use a `switch()` you need to use a `break` if you don't want to continue "falling through" to the other `case`s.

Comment: Oh, my, god. Completely forgot about that. Thank you mate.